# how can i achieve this in c#

Tags: c#, controls, custom-controls

i'm developing a windows form application.in the form, the left part is a tree menu, and the right part is show area. how can i change the show area according to what i click on the tree menu.
[image: my app]
<sub>(source: [126.net](http://img3.ph.126.net/o_braOAtWPgCioFtVHiMmw==/1094937659422071823.jpg))</sub>

i use `treenode` class to implement treemenu like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode27 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("basic operation");
```

what i try to do is use several panels. each panel bounds to a menu item. by setting the `visible` property, i can achieve that goal. but it is too inconvenient.especially when i try to design each panel.
any good suggestion?

Comment: I would look into User Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w29y3h59%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: my English is not very well, especially a large number of words.. can you help me?

Comment: Is there an MSDN in a language that you do speak/read?

Comment: Go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/preferences/locale/?returnurl=%252fen-us%252flibrary%252fw29y3h59%28v%253dvs.100%29.aspx - find your language, and it should redirect you back to the same article above.

Comment: there is. i speak Chinese. but some pages are still English version

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks very much. i am a new programmer

Comment: Might also find this useful: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could design each "Panel" as a new User Control. That way you can design all of the "panels / areas" on their own, independently of the Main Form.

On your Main Form, create a single panel for the right hand side area and add all of the controls to that one panel.

Then when the TreeNode selection event happens you can set all the user controls to `.Visible = false;` except for the one you are showing and set that to `.Visible = true;` and `.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: i understand what you mean. and i think it's a good suggestion. how can i design each "Panel" as a new User Control(i don't understand,can you give more details)? so i can design then independently

Comment: In solution Explorer, Right Click on your Project and Select "Add" then "User Control". Design that, build the project and it will appear in the Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an event handler that will be called at the time of the user clicking the treeview (Use TreeView from the toolBox). You can do that by selecting the treeview on the design page and under properties click on Events. Then select NodeMouseDoubleClick or NodeMouseClick depending upon what you want. Below is a code that captures the values selected...Enjoy...;)

```
  private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
           if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Level == 2)
        {
          //text on the first level
            string text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

        }
         else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Level == 1)
        {
           //text on the second level 
            string text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

        }


        }
```